# Fetching data from MySQL and updating from Python

Tags: python, mysql

Am new in coding
I have a table named 'Capitals' in database 'World'.
This table has 3 columns, namely 'Questions','Answers' and 'Points'.
(Questions column has name of country and answers column has capital of that country)
Intially all column has point=0

I want to fetch this data one by one to python and its GUI(Tkinter) and if the student/user tell capital of the country
i want to add 1 mark to 'Points'. Am able to fetch Questions and answers to python by following code:

No problem in establishing connection with database from python.
No problem in fetching question and answers.

````
    ```
    X=0
    sql2 = "SELECT Questions FROM Capitals"

    mycursor.execute(sql2)
    myresult1 = mycursor.fetchall()
    print(myresult1[x])
    mydb.commit()

    ```
````

i have a tkinter GUI that has a button which named 'SHOW',WHen i click it answer is fetched from following code.

````
    ```
    sql3 = "SELECT Answers FROM Capitals"

    mycursor.execute(sql3)
    myresult1 = mycursor.fetchall()
    print(myresult1[x])
    mydb.commit()

    ```
````

I have a GUI button called 'NEXT', whose command is like 'x=x+1' so that i get next question from database, Till this code works smoothly, but if i want to update 1 mark for correct answers following code doesnt work as 'WHERE' clause of SQL query have to be pointed to particular row in database which is not possible as 'WHERE' clause is not reading a function in Python in my case here is'myresult1[x].
Code i used is

````
    ```
    Sql4="SELECT * FROM Capitals WHERE Questions=myresult1[x]"

    ```
````

MY question is how to loop through 'WHERE' clause of SQL ..
Kindly help

Comment: Please post the appropriate code snippet and edit the question

Comment: Side point; `mydb.commit()` is not needed after your `SELECT` statements, as there is nothing to be committed.

Comment: @S3DEV ok, can u please guide a way to increment score for the fetched Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Sql4` to use a placeholder for the value:

```
Sql4="SELECT * FROM Capitals WHERE Questions=%s"
```

then execute it like this:

```
mycursor.execute(Sql4, (myresult1[x],))
```

passing the `myresult1[x]` in a tuple to `execute()`.

Comment: When i use Sql14="SELECT * FROM Capitals WHERE Questions=%s", how will it point to the exact same Question which came in 'sql2'

Comment: When i use sql4="SELECT * FROM Capitals WHERE Questions=%s, how will it point to the exact Question we fetched via 'sql2' in above code. ALso wen i run your modification in my python  'Point' column in database is not showing increment in points. mydb.commit() is there in end of code . Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Beginner_in_coding You got to ensure `x` is the right index of the question in `myresult1`.

Comment: @Beginner_in_coding If your table has an integer primary id you could use that in the WHERE clause instead of question. Basically you need something to uniquely identify the record.

Comment: I added prmary id integer in database table. Interger primary ID thing works only when i write code as `SELECT * FROM Capitals WHERE Primary ID=1` (or any number we want), but it not looping through, that is if i write code like `WHERE Primary ID=x`, to get same index as of `myresult1` its showing error. How to make it loop through? Thanks in advance

Comment: I added prmary id integer in database table. Interger primary ID thing works only when i write code as SELECT * FROM Capitals WHERE Primary ID=1 (or any number we want), but it not looping through, that is if i write code like WHERE Primary ID=x, to get same index as of myresult1 its showing error. How to make it loop through? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Beginner_in_coding The syntax should be: `mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Capitals WHERE Primary ID=%s', (x,))` to select 1 record. It's very unclear what you are trying to do. Looping or selecting 1 record?

Comment: Say i have 10 ques, with `myresult1[x]` am getting each ques in order as i add `x=x+1` in python code. But wen cmg to change `Point` in db table am not able to do it automatically as SQL query  is `sql4="UPDATE Capitals SET Point=Point+1 WHERE Primary_ID=x`(not reading x here as 1) . Eg When x=1 i am able to get 1st ques n ans from `myresult1[x]`, but dat value of x is not reading in `sql4`.If i change the query to 'sql4="UPDATE Capitals SET Point=Point+1 WHERE Primary_ID=1`,mark is added,but by now value of x=2, 2nd ques comes,Primary ID have to be 2 automatically. How to do it?

Comment: @Beginner_in_coding Try this: `mycursor.execute('UPDATE Capitals SET Point=Point+1 WHERE Primary_ID=%s', (x,))`

Comment: it worked man, Sorry for bothering you,am only a beginner

Comment: am new here so didnt knew it. Sorry,but when i do am getting this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: @Beginner_in_coding Thanks. Good luck with your coding. Try and enjoy it even if you get stuck sometimes. It's a great learning experience.